# Combobox - Auto position in dropdown list

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a simple combobox as follows :

```
                    {
                    xtype: 'combobox',
                    id: 'prd-main-group',
                    fieldLabel: 'ANA MAL GRUBU',
                    inputWidth: 320,
                    labelWidth: 160,
                    labelAlign: 'right',
                    margin: '15 0 0 0',
                    fieldStyle: 'height: 26px; text-align: right; font-size: 12pt; color:#505050',
                    store: articleMain,
                    valueField: 'WHG',
                    displayField: 'WHG_BEZ',
                    queryMode: 'remote',
                    autoSelect: false,
                    selectOnFocus: true,
                    hideTrigger: true,
                    msgTarget: 'side',
                    triggerAction: 'all',
                    typeAhead: true,
                    minChars: 2,
                    listeners: {
                        select: function (combo, selection) {
                            articleBase.proxy.extraParams = {'maingroup': combo.getValue()};
                            Ext.getCmp('prd-base-group').setDisabled(false);
                            Ext.getCmp('prd-base-group').getStore().removeAll();
                            Ext.getCmp('prd-base-group').setValue(null);
                            Ext.getCmp('prd-sub-group').getStore().removeAll();
                            Ext.getCmp('prd-sub-group').setValue(null);
                            articleBase.load();
                        },
                        focus: function(combo) {
                            combo.setValue('');
                        }
                    }
                },
```

When I typed two or more characters, the combobox dropdown list appear and showing the values but no automatically position selected record from the dropdown list.

As you can see attached screen shot, the value completed but drop down list didn't focused selected record!

[image]

My question is, when we type a few chars, the dropdown list should automatically change based on the given chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without Skirtle's Den what will I do :)

We should set `autoLoad: true` parameter in the `store` definition. After that we also should set `queryMode` to `local`. I know it doesn't make sense but when we set `autoLoad`, data loaded as soon as store created!

```
                    {

                    xtype: 'combobox',
                    id: 'prd-main-group',
                    fieldLabel: 'ANA MAL GRUBU',
                    inputWidth: 320,
                    labelWidth: 160,
                    labelAlign: 'right',
                    margin: '15 0 0 0',
                    fieldStyle: 'height: 26px; text-align: right; font-size: 12pt; color:#505050',
                    store: articleMain,
                    valueField: 'WHG',
                    displayField: 'WHG_BEZ',
                    queryMode: 'local',
                    autoSelect: true,
                    forceSelection: true,
                    msgTarget: 'side',
                    triggerAction: 'all',
                    listeners: {
                        select: function (combo, selection) {
                            articleBase.proxy.extraParams = {'maingroup': combo.getValue()};
                            Ext.getCmp('prd-base-group').setDisabled(false);
                            Ext.getCmp('prd-base-group').getStore().removeAll();
                            Ext.getCmp('prd-base-group').setValue(null);
                            Ext.getCmp('prd-sub-group').getStore().removeAll();
                            Ext.getCmp('prd-sub-group').setValue(null);
                            articleBase.load();
                        },
                        focus: function(combo) {
                            combo.setValue('');
                        }
                    }
                }
```

And here is the store definition :

```
var articleMain = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
model: 'ArticleMainGroup',
autoLoad: true,
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>create/get_product_main_group',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'articleMainGroup',
        idProperty: 'ID'
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try with `autoSelect: true`.

Answer (score 0):

`ForceSelection="true"` + `TypeAhead="true"` and it should work